# Fetch data from two tables based on a column from particular table

Tags: mysql

[image]i have two tables as :

Table t1:

```
+-----+----+  
| i1  | c1 |  
+-----+----+  
| 11  | abc |  
| 22  | bbc |  
| 33  | cbc |  
+-----+-----+
```

Table t2:

```
+-----+----+  
| i2  | c2 |  
+-----+----+  
| 22  | cc |  
| 33  | bb |  
| 33  | bb |  
| 44  | aa |
| 22  | cc |  
+-----+----+
```

and output should be as

```
+----+-----+----+  
| i1 | c1  | c2 |
+----+-----+----+   
| 22 | bbc | cc |
| 33 | cbc | bb |
+----+-----+----+
```

i tried joins but couldn't get the exact output

fetch table1.user_id,table1affiliate_id where table1.affiliate_id=table2.id 
should give reslut only from table one eg:table1  has 26 rows, and table2 has 125 rows ,where table2 has all  26 rows of table1 and more , so i need the output to print only 26 related fields from two tables...

Comment: *"i tried joins but couldn't get the exact output"* - Nonetheless, you should have posted what you tried; it will help others to see if you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: SELECT table1.i1,table1.c2,table2.c2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1 ON  table2  table1.c1=table2.i2

Comment: you need to edit your question and not place code in comments please http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43498778/edit

Comment: you've also been given an answer below; seems like guesswork to me though but you can try it. Edit: Yep, I was right.

Comment: What would you want if 33 had bb and jj in table 2?

Comment: I m new to questioning stack overflow i will try my best in future thanks for the suggestion , but that query is giving me 4 rows instead of 2 rows i need the result only two rows from table1 which is matching in table2 Thanks !!

Comment: there is no such data its all duplicate data i need to remove from that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL will help you :)

```
SELECT t1.i1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.i1 = t2.i2
GROUP BY t1.i1, t1.c1
```

Comment: And why don't you want to get row with i1 = 11? Any secret conditions?))

Comment: i have two tables where table 1 has id and user_name and the table2 has ids and emails where the user may have many email but i need to fetch only important email id so this is the head ache ...

Answer (score 0):

Implicit joins should be avoided

```
   drop table if exists t1;
    create table t1(i1 int, c1 varchar(3));
    insert into t1 values  
    ( 11  ,'abc'),  
    ( 22  ,'bbc'),  
    ( 33  ,'cbc');  


drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 ( i2 int, c2 varchar(2));  
insert into t2 values
( 22  , 'cc'),  
( 33  , 'bb'),  
( 33  , 'bb'),  
( 44  , 'aa'),
( 22  , 'cc');  


select distinct t1.i1,t1.c1,t2.c2
from t1
join t2 on t2.i2 = t1.i1

+------+------+------+
| i1   | c1   | c2   |
+------+------+------+
|   22 | bbc  | cc   |
|   33 | cbc  | bb   |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please check the image and help me sort it out Thanks ALL